# Kinesis to Lambda - Parsing Data

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, lambda, base64, amazon-kinesis

I'm following this tutorial to push data from my API Gateway to a Kinesis stream :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html#api-gateway-get-and-add-records-to-stream

I have my Body Mapping Template setup as.....

```
{
    "StreamName": "my-stream-name",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode($input.path('$.Data'))",
    "PartitionKey": "$input.path('$.PartitionKey')"
}
```

...and have put the following in the Request Body of an API test...

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Foo": "A",
    "Bar": "B"
  },
  "PartitionKey": "some key"
}
```

I've then created a Lambda Function which has a trigger set up against the same Kinesis Stream. However, I'm struggling to decode/deserialise the records coming in from Kinesis.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {        
        let payload = JSON.parse(Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii'))      
    });
};
```

It seems that the data is being serialised to Kinesis in a non-JSON format.  The value for `record.kinesis.data` in the forEach loop is

> e0Zvbz1BLCBCYXI9Qn0=

...which when push through Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii')

returns as

> {Foo=A, Bar=B}

not

> {"Foo":"A", "Bar":"B"}

Main aim is obviously to get payload to in a state where I can say `console.log(payload.Foo)`

Any hints as to what I should be doing/looking for would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else out there

I had my Body Mapping Template setup as.....

```
{
    "StreamName": "my-stream-name",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode($input.path('$.Data'))",
    "PartitionKey": "$input.path('$.PartitionKey')"
}
```

Now changed to handle the json....

```
{
    "StreamName": "my-stream-name",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode($input.json('$.Data'))",
    "PartitionKey": "$input.path('$.PartitionKey')"
}
```

where...

```
($input.json('$.Data'))
```

is the change :)